# Chaining and Composing Jooq commands

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I have a query like this:

1. select a row
2. create row with values from the row above (there are more that 1 value).

Technically it's possible to express in one SQL request, but 
with jooq there will be a value round-trip between application and db server.

```
jooq.select(TABLE_A.FIELD_A, TABLE_A.FIELD_B).from(TABLE_A)                
            .where(TABLE_A.ID.eq(id))
            .fetchOne().map(r ->
            jooq.insertInto(AUDIT)
            .columns(AUDIT.FIELD_A, AUDIT.FIELD_B)
            .values(r.value1(), r.value2()).execute())


select field_a, field_b into @a, @b from TABLE where ID = ?;
insert into AUDIT (field_a, field_b) values(@a, @b);
```

This is a demo query. I am interesting in tools helping to do composing, rather than in workarounds for a specific query.

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you mean by "composing" and "workarounds"? E.g. why is your suggestion not interesting for you? What would the ideal solution look like?

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ supports `INSERT .. SELECT`. You shouldn't have a client roundtrip between the two statements but write this instead:

**SQL:**

```sql
insert into AUDIT (FIELD_A, FIELD_B)
select FIELD_A, FIELD_B from TABLE where ID = ?;
```

**Java:**

```java
jooq.insertInto(AUDIT, AUDIT.FIELD_A, AUDIT.FIELD_B)
    .select(DSL.select(TABLE.FIELD_A, TABLE.FIELD_B)
               .from(TABLE)
               .where(TABLE.ID.eq(id)))
    .execute();
```